# Problemas para deshabilitar un botón

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tengo dos botones uno para validar la línea y otro para salir del formulario:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type="submit" Id="validacion" value="Validar esta Línea" 
  class="btn btn-primary validarlinea" tabindex="27">
                            <button id="btn-add-bi-cancelar" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" 
  tabindex="26" class="m-l-20 btn btn-info btn-rounded salir">Salir</button>
```

Cuando se pulsa en "Validar" se inicia el proceso validate y se genera un `ajax()`, durante ese proceso me interesaría que el usuario no interactuara con la aplicación y hacerle ver que el sistema está trabajando mediante el siguiente código:

```
$("#validacion").hover(function(){
 $(this).css("background-color", "red");
 $(this).css("cursor", "wait");
 }, function(){
 $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
$("#btn-add-bi-cancelar").hover(function(){
 $(this).css("background-color", "red");
 $(this).css("cursor", "wait");
 }, function(){
 $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Dicho código cuando el proceso acaba se revierte.

Consigo que los botones durante el proceso aparezcan de color rojo, y que el puntero cambie de aspecto a wait.

Pero de todas maneras aunque cambie el aspecto ; el evento click , se produce
Intento deshabilitar los botones con el siguiente código , pero no funciona

```
$("#btn-add-bi-cancelar").disabled=true;
```

¿Podrían decirme donde me equivoco?

Gracias anticipadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que no es así como se activa esa propiedad.

Debes conocer la diferencia etre **propiedad** y **atributo**:

- Las propiedades son propias es decir, pertenecen ya a un objeto u elemento
- Mientras que los atributos se les asignan a ese elemento u objeto de forma externa o indirecta.

Así es como se asigna una propiedad **`disabled`** a un botón en JQuery:

```
$("#btn-add-bi-cancelar").prop('disabled', true);
```